# Width and height of binary tree is $\theta(n)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science, trees

we know this definition:

Given a binary tree, Width of a tree is maximum of widths of all levels.

Let us consider the below example tree.

```
     1
    /  \
   2    3
 /  \     \
4    5     8 
          /  \
         6    7
```

For the above tree,
width of level 1 is 1,
width of level 2 is 2,
width of level 3 is 3
width of level 4 is 2.

So the maximum width of the tree is 3.

can we have a binary tree with Height $\theta(n)$  and Width  $\theta(n)$

My solution:
is YES. for example a binary tree with one-node:

```
     1
```

am i right?

Comment: You are right that the singleton tree has height and width $\theta(n)$.  Actually, the question only makes sense for a given (infinite) set of trees.  Because, take any individual tree $T$.  Having width $\theta(n)$ means that there exist constants $c$ and $d$ such that $cn \leq Width(T) \leq dn$.  If you have only one tree, then you can always fnd such constants.  However if you have an infinite set of trees, it makes sense to ask if the above inequality holds for all trees for some $c$ and $d$.  If your set of trees is the set of all binary trees, I think the answer is no.

Comment: I think the question should be read as "for each $n$, can we have a binary tree..."

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

the Symbol $\Theta (n)$ is related to Average case for set of (bigger) n. So with one tree you couldn't say the tree with one-node has $\Theta (n)$ in height and width.